# How can I make userform to work like inputbox?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have Workbook named Test. And in The Test I have code that runs when the workbook is opened it shows me UserForm1 which asks me to login with username and password and it will hide applications so only the UserForm1 is seen. The problem is that you can open Excel again and open a new workbook, and there you can go to the VBA and see workbook Test's code and close or modify it.

If the login would be requested in the input box, you can not do the trick and circumvent the login part. Input Box allows you only click in the workbooks Input Box you can't press ALT + F11 and go to VBA code or if you try to open new Workbook and in there goto VBA code there wouldn't be the Test's code. How to do this, with the UserForm?

Thank you so much for all your help in advance!
If it helps I can copy the code to do this , but it's a little mess.

Comment: What you are trying here ultimately **can not be done**. There is no way to properly protect your code. What if a user opens the workbook, and just simply **doesn't enable macros**? So even if you can solve this somehow, there will be another easy way around your login form.

Comment: You can protect your project and then auto execute your Userform but the enabling macros part is a problem I have experienced

Comment: If user open the Workbook and don't enable macros workbook only shows sheet named Login and in there is 2 lines of text which tells user to come back with macros on. All other sheets are hidden before workbook is closed with xlSheetVeryHidden only Login sheet isn't hidden. You can goaround this also but I am working on it also. @vapic

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen   How can I do this? Sorry I don't know I am new to Excel and VBA.

Comment: In your Project Viewer, right click your project then under the protection tab insert your password. You will then need to insert the password when you want to access your script for each instance you have the document open

Comment: @RasmusPiirtola "You can goaround this also but I am working on it also." I'll nominate you to a Nobel prize if you can figure this one out. :) In the end, the user can do whatever they want with your "protected" file. The VBA password is very easy to crack, 10 minutes tops including google search. Keep trying, but in the end you will realize: there is no way to properly protect your VBA code, and no way to properly autenticate users in Excel using VBA. Every method is easily countered.

Comment: 'Every method is easily countered` - the easily depends on your user base, their knowledge (of how to even search for ways and also understand them enough to implement) and also their desire. So, certain methods may be *good enough* to produce the desire effect that you want.

Comment: True, but I assumed Rasmus's users are not totally beginners, as they are capable of pressing Alt+F11 to open the VBA editor and do things there. If someone can get this far, in my experience they can use the internet to search for solutions. But you are right, for some user bases some methods can be restricting enough.

Comment: Normally protecting the VBA project is enough. It is just so nobody goes into the project and screws things up, not because people are trying to be malicious. If an employee were to use a code breaking method to break the VBA password, it would obviously be for malicious reasons and that employee would soon be looking for another job. Always have backups.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers!

Comment: @RasmusPiirtola, please indicate whose comment provided you with the answer so that they can formulate it into an Answer and then insert it as an Answer to this question.

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen Sorry I am new to this ,but I used your answer the projected VBA project works fine.

Comment: We all learning, so no problem.  I will post an answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is protect your project,  then auto execute your macro.

To protect you project do the following:

In your Project Viewer, right click your project then under the protection tab insert your password. You will then need to insert the password when you want to access your script for each instance you have the document open.